# Blackberry max bytes for IPPP connection

Tags: networking, blackberry

I'm trying to determine the max number of KB allowed for an IPPP connection through a BES a BlackBerry is connected to.

In a develoment environment, I can check this via the 'IPPP.connection.MaxNumberOfKBytesToSend' variable inside the 'rimpublic.property' file.

Does anyone know how to detect this on a device running in the field?

Thanks,

Dan

Answer (score 0):

In Blackberry Manager under Servers there should be an entry for your MDS service.  Select that then select Edit Properties on the right.  In the options, under Flow Control, you will find the Maximum KB/Connection option.  This is the BES equivalent to `IPPP.connection.MaxNumberOfKBytesToSend` in the MDS simulator properties file.

Comment: Thanks!  I'm going to try this and report back!